# Save methods and results

Tags: c#, oop

I currently have a method to save a user.

```
public PersonDto Save(PersonDto personDto)
```

However, if, while saving, I find there is a duplicate username, or some other issue with the data - my only way to respond to this is to throw an exception.

```
throw new Exception("Username exists");
```

I have read that exceptions shouldn't be used for 'Business Requirement Transgressions'.

Is there a better way to return results to my calling methods? I need to return to PersonDto, but also, some information about any issues. Is there a common practice or model for doing this? Maybe return a 'SaveResult' object, which contains a `Object SavedObject` (in this case, my PersonDto), as well as some other properties like `string SaveResult` and `bool Success`?

Comment: I recommend logging to a file when issues like this occurs in your code instead of throwing exceptions. I have log files for the majority of my programs.

Comment: The guidelines (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229030.aspx) clearly state: DO report execution failures by throwing exceptions, and DO NOT return error codes. If a Save method is unable to save, that's an execution failure.

Comment: Is the PersonDto instance that you return the same one that was passed in? If so, what is the point? The caller has a reference to it already, right?

Comment: Kris - the personDto gets some information added to it. If it's a new person, the PersonId will not be set before saving. This then gets set, and returned to the called in PersonDto.PersonId. On updates, it's probably the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a `SaveResult` approach to your problem e.g.

```
public class SaveResult
{
    public PersonDto { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

var result = Save(person);

if (!result.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorMessage);
}
```

Or something like that. This will allow you to pass back the `PersonDto`, but also signal to the API caller that an error occurred when trying to save.

There's nothing really wrong with throwing an exception, but as you also want to return the person DTO, then you might as well use a specific method return type for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks Jason - that is an EXACT duplicate of what I was trying while waiting for a reply. Except, to make the 'SaveResult' generic, I take a 'Object', instead of a 'PersonDto', so that it can be used for all objects.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe implement a generic wrapper for use with all such requests.

```
enum Disposition
{
    OK,
    Warning,
    Error
}

class Response<T>
{
    public T Result { get; set; }
    public Disposition Disposition { get; set; } 
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

i.e.:

```
public Response<PersonDto> Save(PersonDto personDto)
```

This way you can specify some metadata for each of your return values.